# What's the correct return type for this TypeScript function?

Tags: typescript

This is probably a basic TypeScript understanding question.

Google Cloud samples use JavaScript. I'm trying to convert one to TypeScript.

From: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets#storage-list-buckets-nodejs

The JS code is:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function listBuckets() {
  // Lists all buckets in the current project

  const [buckets] = await storage.getBuckets();
  console.log('Buckets:');
  buckets.forEach(bucket => {
    console.log(bucket.name);
  });
  return listBuckets;
}

listBuckets().catch(console.error);
```

The type definitions for getBuckets are:

```
getBuckets(options?: GetBucketsRequest): Promise<GetBucketsResponse>;
getBuckets(options: GetBucketsRequest, callback: GetBucketsCallback): void;
getBuckets(callback: GetBucketsCallback): void;
```

And the type definition for GetBucketsResponse is:

`export declare type GetBucketsResponse = [Bucket[], {}, Metadata];`

I don't know what return value to use. If I set the return type to `Bucket[]`, it fails with `The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.`

And if I try `async function listBuckets(): Promise<Bucket[]>`, it fails on the return, saying `Type '() => Promise<Bucket[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Bucket[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your are not returning anything from function, So return `Promise<void>`**

```
async function listBuckets(): Promise<void> {
  // Lists all buckets in the current project

  const [buckets] = await storage.getBuckets();
  console.log('Buckets:');
  buckets.forEach(bucket => {
    console.log(bucket.name);
  });
}
```

It is already promise, you dont need to create promise again.

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

```
function listBuckets() {
  // Lists all buckets in the current project

  return storage.getBuckets().then((buckets) => {
   console.log('Buckets:');
   buckets.forEach(bucket => {
     console.log(bucket.name);
   });
  return buckets
});

}

listBuckets().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Sorry, missed a line. I return the function itself :D. Maybe actually that's wrong. I just noticed in the Google Cloud example they don't do it. But it was working fine in JS, for whatever reason.

Comment: lol if already it return promise why u are awaiting, just write thenable chain and return the same.

`promise.then(x => {/*do something here */ return x; })`